# Understanding the enqueue method for Linked List Queue

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

Im having trouble understanding the code for the enqueue method for a linkedlist queue. I understand the dequeue(), isEmpty(), First() and size(). Firstly here is there LinearNode class to create the new node objects:

```
public class LinearNode<T> {
    private T element;
    private LinearNode<T> next;

    /**
     * Constructor: Creates an empty node.
     */
    public LinearNode() {
        next = null;
        element = null;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor: Creates a node storing the specified element.
     * @param elem  The specified element that is to be kept by this LinearNode.
     */
    public LinearNode(T elem) {
        next = null;
        element = elem;
    }

    /**
     *  Returns the node that follows this one.
     * @return  The node that follows this one.
     */
    public LinearNode<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    /**
     *  Sets the node that follows this one.
     * @param node  The node which is to follow this one.
     */
    public void setNext(LinearNode<T> node) {
        next = node;
    }

    /**
     *  Returns the element stored in this node.
     * @return  The element that is kept within this node.
     */
    public T getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    /**
     *  Sets the element stored in this node.
     * @param elem  The element that is to be kept within this node.
     */
    public void setElement(T elem) {
        element = elem;
    }
}
```

And here is the Enqueue method

```
public void enqueue(T element) {
    LinearNode<T> tmp = new LinearNode<T>(element);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        // set-up front to point to the new node
        front = tmp;
    } else {
        // add the node after the old tail node
        rear.setNext(tmp);
    }
    // update rear to point to the new node
    rear = tmp;
    count++; // increment size
}
```

The part of the code im getting confused is `rear.setNext(tmp);` I mean shouldnt it be `temp.setNext(rear);` How can you use the method .setNext(); on the `LinearNode<T> rear;` when you havnt made new object called rear the only new object I can see made is called `temp` ??

Edit
Here the LinkQueue Class that contains the Enqueue method:

```
public class LinkedQueue<T> implements QueueADT<T> {
private LinearNode<T> front; // front node of the queue
private LinearNode<T> rear;  // rear node of the queue
private int count;           // the current size of the queue

/**
 * Constructor: Creates an empty Queue.
 */
public LinkedQueue() { 
    count = 0;
    /* the following assignments are not actually necessary as references
     *  are initialised automatically to null, 
     *  but they are included for clarity.
     */
    front = null;
    rear = null;
}
```

Comment: Who and **where** are front and rear?

Comment: Just edited the post have a look

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand from the code, front and rear are simply pointers. They are used to point to the first and last nodes of the queue. So when you say:

```
rear.setNext(tmp);
```

you are tagging the new node after the last node of the queue.

consider this queue: 1,2,3,4

In this queue,
front=1
rear=4

```
enqueue(5)
```

this results in tmp=5

`rear.setNext(5)` results in

1,2,3,4,5

`rear=tmp` results in 
rear=5 resetting the rear pointer to the last node

Answer (score 0):

If the `LinkedQueue<T>` is empty `tmp`  will be head and tail of the list at same time. Both pointers `front` and `tail` will be linked to the new node.

Else: `rear` point to the object stored at the tail. Doing `rear.setNext(tmp);` it will just set to that object a new following node `tmp`. Then updates the `rear` reference with the correct new object `rear = tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the direction of links in the Que.

Here is a Que with 5 persons in the line waiting for the assistant. They move toward the assistant but they are linked in the opposite direction:

5<--4<--3<--2<--1      :     :-) (How can I assist you?)

A new person arrives: 6

6<--5<--4<--3<--2<--1  :     :-) (How can I assist you?)

The first person is done: (He/she has been the first in and that's why he/she is also the first out: FIFO)

6<--5<--4<--3<--2      :     :-) (How can I assist you?)